# process.exit() not exiting process from within express .close callback, only with nodemon

Tags: node.js, express, process, nodemon, graceful-shutdown

I am trying to create some setup and teardown logic for an expressjs server.  Here's my entry code:

```js
import fs from "fs";
import express from "express";
import { setRoutes } from "./routes";

let app = express();

const server = app.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log(` Mock Server is now running on port : ${8080}`);
});

app = setRoutes(app);

function stop() {
  fs.rmdirSync("./uploads", { recursive: true });
  fs.mkdirSync("uploads");
  console.log("\n Uploads folder purged");

  server.on("close", function () {
    console.log("⬇  Shutting down server");
    process.exit();
  });

  server.close();
}

process.on("SIGINT", stop);

// Purge sw images on restart
process.once("SIGUSR2", function () {
  fs.rmdirSync("./uploads/swimages", { recursive: true });
  console.log(" Software Images folder purged");
  process.kill(process.pid, "SIGUSR2");
});
```

The npm script to start this up is `"start": "FORCE_COLOR=3 nodemon index.js --exec babel-node"`.

The setup and restart logic works as expected.  I get   `Mock Server is now running on port : 8080` logged to console on startup.  When I save a file, nodemon restarts the server, and the code in `process.once` is executed.  When I want to shut it all down, I `ctrl + c` in the terminal.  The cleanup logic from within the `stop` function is run.  However, the process bever fully exits.  In the terminal,  am still stuck in the process, and I have to hit `ctrl + c` *again* to fully exit the process.  It looks like this:

[image]

As far as I know there are no open connections (other questions mentioned that if there is a `keep-alive` connection still open, the server will not close properly, but as far as I can tell, that is not the case).  I have tried different variations of `server.close(callback)`, `server.on('close', callback)`, `process.exit()`, `process.kill(process.pid)`, etc, but nothing seems to fully exit the process.

Note that if I simply run `node index.js`, I do not have this issue.  The cleanup logic runs, and the process exits to completion without issue.  It seems to be an issue when using nodemon only.

I don't want other developers to have to wait for cleanup logic to run and then hit ctrl + c again. What am I missing to run my cleanup logic and fully exit the process in the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

There is an open connection for sure. Check this package that can tell you which one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/wtfnode

Comment: So that's a very interesting package, that told me that my use of [WatchJS](https://github.com/melanke/Watch.JS/) is an open connection when trying to shut down the server.  But I'm having a hard time believing that's my real issue.   If I simply do `node index.js` from the terminal, a `ctrl + c` properly shuts everything down as expected.  But with nodemon, I get the issue described.  Why would that happen with nodemon?